# Will I benefit from windows drivers in virtual machine?

Tags: drivers, virtualization

I ordered a Sony Vaio VPC-SE1 (S-series) laptop, but I want to keep using Ubuntu.
Searching the internet for issues with Vaio laptops in Ubuntu, there could be 1 particular issue that really bugs me, being the fact that the laptops run hotter in Ubuntu so that the fan is almost always on...

I'm looking for solutions to keep using Ubuntu with the system not overheating and the fans not spinning like mad, should the issue be present.

A possibilty I had in mind was to use windows, with all sony drivers for the windows platform, as a host for ubuntu in a virtual machine with virtualbox, with the virtual machine automatically starting up after booting windows.
I'd expect that in this configuration ubuntu will benefit from the windows drivers and will not have the fan issue at least, or so I hope??

Answer (score 1):

If Windows is handling the bare-metal side of things, I think you're probably correct and it'll fix your power issues... But you'll be running two operating systems all the time which will use more RAM and CPU all the time.

If Ubuntu is on bare-metal and Windows is the virtualised OS, that's not going to help you at all. Windows won't have access to the hardware to monitor or help change temperatures.